# Porque me resulta NullPointerException en Netbeans 8.2 con Ireports en un solo reporte

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

me genera este error en un reporte especifico en los demás no.. y no entiendo por que...este es mi procedimiento para llamar al reporte, eso si solo sucede cuando ejecuto la aplicación, por que en el dentro del netbeans con el plugin del ireport si me genera el reporte

```
public void reporteproce(int idprocedimientos)
    {
        try 
        {
                ConexionBD cc = new ConexionBD();
                Connection conect = cc.conexion();
                //System.out.println(idprocedimiento);
                JasperReport reporte=(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("ReporteBronc.jasper");
                Map parametro = new HashMap();
                parametro.put("idprocedimiento",idprocedimientos);
                JasperPrint j = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro,conect);
                JasperViewer jv =new JasperViewer(j,false);
                jv.setTitle("Broncocospia Respiratoria");
                jv.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al Mostrar Reporte "+e);
                                }
    }
```

.....este es el código del botón

```
    private void BReporteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //SI SE HA ECHO CLIC EN EL JTABLE PACIENTES SELECCIONANDO UN REGISTRO 
    int i=jTablePacientes.getSelectedRow();
    if(i==-1)
                {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jTablePacientes,"Porfavor Elija Un Registro"); 
                }else
                    {
                    GenerarReporte reportito = new GenerarReporte();
                    //***********BUSCANDO SI EL PACIENTE TIENE ALGUNA ATENCION****************************
                        try{
                            ConexionBD conectar = new ConexionBD();
                            Connection cn = conectar.conexion();
                            sent = cn.createStatement();
                            int x=Integer.parseInt(TxtConsulta.getText());
                            //System.out.println(x);
                            reportito.reporteproce(x);
                            resultado.close();
                            sent.close();
                            }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                System.err.println(""+e.getMessage());
                                }
                }
```

y asi me sale en el netbeans..pero ya en la aplicacion me sale ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porfavor echenme una mano que estoy estancado

así me sale en la aplicación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que me bota el log 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "eso si solo sucede cuando ejecuto la aplicación por que en el" ???

Comment: AyaDrg,  te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: ¿Utilizas maven, ant?, ¿estás agregando las librerias necesaria para el reporte? Podrias indicar el plugin utilizado.

Comment: @cjara hola gracias por contestar estoy usando iReport-4.0.2: con 11 librerias que vienen...la cuestion es que el otro reporto si me lo genera sin problemas...es solo con este...genere la consulta sql y si me muestra los datos a reportar...pero no se que es lo que pasa

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir más detalle de la excepción lanzada?

Comment: @cjara hola tengo un reporte igual en otra pantalla del mismo sistema y ese si me sale bien...no se por que este no....el valor que le paso al procedimiento es 1 y si esta como entero,,y también se encuentra en el bd..entonces no se por que no sale..gracias por tratar de ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

he resuelto el problema, al parecer era algún problema de compatibilidad con el netbeans 8.2 y el jdk lo que hice fue bajarme un archivo ejecutable de la pagina de Oracol que tenia el netbenas y el jdk incluidos!..con eso ya me salio el reporte saludos!!